# Multiple Wireless Interfaces each connects to a specific SSID

Tags: networking, wifi

I have multiple GoPro cameras, which are running as multiple access points. I bought a few wifi dongles trying to connect each dongle to each camera.

My plan is to specify each dongle (with its stable interface name like `wlxe84e07796099`) to connect to a specific GoPro SSID like `GoPro_num1`.

I used the GUI version of the `dhcpcd` that comes with the Raspbian (v5.4) on the top right corner of the screen. With it I can manually connect each interface to different wifi networks. How can persist this config even after reboot?

P.S. Each interface should only connect to its designated SSID, otherwise it should not connecting to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no GUI tool, but it can easily be done by editing a couple of files.

See **Use different wpa_supplicant files** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Can't believe it is this simple!!! Thank you!!

Comment: For people who don't want to click the link... just `Create a file named wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant/ e.g. wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf will only be used by wlan0`